# Google Drive API v3 suddenly started exporting docs with Base64 encoded images

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I've been using Google Drive v3 to export Google Docs to html for the past four years. (https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/DriveV3/DriveService.html#export_file-instance_method)

`text/html` MIME type.

```rb
      drive = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
      drive.authorization = google_credentials

      html = drive.export_file(
        external_id,
        'text/html'
      )
```

It always exported images with URLs (like `<img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/hashhashhashhash123" />`).

Now, out of nowhere, it started exporting those as base64 encoded images **for new authorized accounts only**, (like `<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAetcetc..." />`)

Yes, if I get my previously authorized account to authorize the export, it exports images as links, for recently authorized account, it exports images base64 encoded. (The request URL looks exactly the same for both).

First, I couldn't find **any** information out there about this change (thanks a lot, google!). Has this change been published anywhere?

Second, is there a way to get this exported output in the old (imgs as links) without doing a huge hasty refactor?

Thanks!

Comment: can I see your code?

Comment: Sure @LindaLawton-DaImTo, just added, pretty standard though.

Comment: external_id is the google doc id

Comment: @PedroBernardes Since you have no issues with your code, but rather with the response being given by the API this will fall as a non programming question. I can see that you have submitted this on the Google Issue tracker so Google Engineer can have a look at it. Please wait for their response.

Comment: I didn't know that was even supported let me see if I have a contact on that team anymore I can ping about it.    Seems strange if it used to work.    in the meantime I would Pop it up on the issue forums

Answer (score 0):

So, we worked around it by changing everything and importing as a ZIP. The size limit can be worked around using another endpoint. Reference code for people having this issue:

```
drive_file = drive.get_file document_id, fields: 'exportLinks'
response = HTTParty.get drive_file.export_links["application/zip"],
                        headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer #{token}" }

File.open(filename, 'wb') do |f|
  f.write response.body
end

// Work with the zip
```